# タイトルに "クローズ" と含まれた質問の対処

Tags: 討議

タイトルに "クローズ" が含まれた質問が見受けられます。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA

これらの質問は、サイトの機能であるクローズではなく、タイトルを編集し "クローズ" をつけています。

特にこちらの質問では、質問が解決した際に編集機能を使い "クローズ" にしてしまっています。
[svn updateしようとするとSSL handshake failed: SSL disabled due to library version mismatchが起きる点の解消方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6505/%EF%BC%9C%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%EF%BC%9Esvn-update%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8ssl-handshake-failed-ssl-disabled-due-to-library-version)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/6505/revisions

このような質問は、どのように対処していくのがよいのでしょうか。

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143757 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251

Answer (score 10, accepted):

現在該当する2つの質問は、どちらも周囲からヒントをもらいながら質問者の方で自己解決したもののようですね。

対処としては、回答にチェックマークを付ける形で解決済みにしてもらえるよう質問者に働きかけ、レスポンスがない場合はできる範囲でその形にもっていくようにするのがよいと思います。役立つQ&Aにできればそれに越したことはない、という考え方です。

1. 編集して「クローズ」をタイトルから消す:

   「タイトルに『クローズ』と付ければ解決済みになるんだ」という誤解が広がらないようにするためです。
2. 解決済みにする方法をコメントする:

   コメントの例:

   > 自己解決された場合は、解決策を回答として投稿し、後でチェックマークを付けておくとよいですよ。
   >
   > // 私は場合によって以下のような理由を添えています。
   > 他の方の参考になると思います。
   > 未回答の質問一覧に出なくなります。
   > 解決済みということが分かりやすくなります。
   > // こちらの理由はまだ書いたことがありませんが：
   > 回答に票が入ると信用度を獲得できます。
3. 質問者のコメントなどから解決方法が読み取れる場合: 解決方法を代わりに回答として投稿する

   「代わりに投稿した回答から信用度を得るのは質問者にわるい」と感じる場合は、コミュニティ wiki として投稿することで、その回答への投票からは信用度が発生しないようにすることができます。回答欄の右下にある「コミュニティ wiki」というチェックボックスにチェックを付けて投稿すればokです。
4. 質問者がどう解決したのか読み取れない場合:

   ケースバイケースですが、今後役立つ回答が付きそうになく、質問自体にも他の人の役に立つ要素が見受けられない場合は、クローズか削除がよいかもしれません。