# クローズされた質問でも「自己解決した場合は自分で回答」してもらうべき？

Tags: 討議

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/8609/8000

この質問は、自己解決した旨が[質問の編集によって記載されました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/8609/revisions)。当該の版はロールバックされ、自己解決した場合は回答に記述をといったコメントがされています。

しかし現時点までに回答が投稿されないままに、「質問内容がはっきりしない」という理由でクローズされてしまいました。

原則的には[「自己解決しました」と質問文に書く代わりに自分で回答を付けてもらう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1676/8000)、でいいと思うのですが、それは「Q&Aとして役に立つから」という理由が背景にあると思います。

オフトピック、説明不十分、質問の範囲が広すぎる質問にもそれは言えるでしょうか？

また、自己回答待ちならクローズを保留したり、クローズ済みの質問がこのようなケースになった場合は再オープンするべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問がクローズすべきであれば、回答があるかないかにもかかわらずに、クローズ投票するべきだと思います。

もし編集でその質問を改善できれば、それがベストだと思いますが、もしできない場合には、クローズ投票してください。

実は残っても問題はないです。長期的にあまり役に立たない質問・回答がたまることになりますが、検索にあまり出ないです。もし[閲覧数が多い質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+views%3A1000)なら、キーワードとして質問が当たっていますので、興味ある人がいますので、努力すればいいと思います。