# コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理

Tags: 討議, コメント, 回答の仕方

質問に対するコメントのやりとりのみで質問者の疑問が解決し、システム的には未回答の質問として残ることがあります。理想的には、コメント回答を書いたユーザか質問者自身が回答追記＆承認を行えばよいのですが、単に面倒だったり、不慣れユーザだったりとそこまでの対処が行われることは稀です。

一方で他ユーザからは未回答質問として見えるため、あまり好ましくないのも事実です。コメント欄で質問者に回答追記を促すケースもありますが、さほど効果が上がっていないように思えます。

質問者やコメント回答ユーザでない第三者ユーザでも可能な行動として、「**コメント欄の内容を引用転記した回答をつけ、その回答をコミュニティwiki化する**」という対応はどうでしょう？

- 回答に変換され、将来的に誰か（or自分）が賛成投票することで、システム的にも未回答として扱われなくなります。

  - https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1789/ 参照
- コミュニティwiki化は必須ではないですが、中立的立場から回答することができます。（"他人の手柄を奪った"という印象を減らす効果）

Comment: タイトルに「クローズ」と書かれた場合（これもコメントのやりとりで解決している）の対応についても似たような話がありました。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1677

Answer (score 9, accepted):

関連メタ質問「[タイトルに “クローズ” と含まれた質問の対処](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1676/)」の回答より

> 3. 質問者のコメントなどから解決方法が読み取れる場合: 解決方法を代わりに回答として投稿する
>
> 「代わりに投稿した回答から信用度を得るのは質問者にわるい」と感じる場合は、コミュニティ wiki として投稿することで、その回答への投票からは信用度が発生しないようにすることができます。回答欄の右下にある「コミュニティ wiki」というチェックボックスにチェックを付けて投稿すればokです。

Comment: このメタ投稿自身が自己記述な該当ケースとなってました… 同意見を引用してクローズしたいと思います。