# 「コミュニティ wiki 」の使い方は、以下のようでいいですか?

Tags: サポート, コミュニティwiki

[SymPy Liveの和集合unionの正しい使い方を教えて下さい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72753/)

上記の質問がコメント欄のやり取りで解決しました。そこで [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1812/) を参考に「コミュニティ wiki」の回答として投稿したのですが、これで使い方はあっているでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

あっていなかったので編集いたしました。

コミュニティ wiki として回答を投稿する場合も、回答の中身は必要です。[元の投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/72755/1)は内容自体は回答になっておりませんでしたので、回答になるよう編集してみました。